# VIM netrw shows directories as files (tree view)

Tags: vim, netrw

I am running VIM version 8.2.501 with netrw v168 and I have spotted the following issue. In some cases nested directories appear as files and not as directories. This happens in a few use cases but the following one is a way to reproduce it.

- Set netrw to use tree style i.e. set `let g:netrw_liststyle = 3` in your .vimrc
- Open netrw `:e.`
- Open a nested directory

[image]

- Press i to toggle modes until you return to tree view
- You can't see all directories and directories appear as files (you can't expand them anymore)

[image]

After that, I can't close the netrw buffer with `<c-6>`. Refreshing the buffer `<c-l>` or toggling modes again does not fix the issue either. The only way to have your directories again is to  close and open the directories above e.g. close/open `foo` will make `foo1` appear again then close/open `foo1` will make `foo2` appear again etc.

Anyone else with this problem? Any fixes?

P.S. I observed that this can also happen when you create a new directory. The buffer refreshes and other directories appear as files. Looks like this view has a lot of bugs

Comment: I noticed the same thing when I'm looking a directory in tree view, then switch to another program, then switch back to Vim. Are you using gVim or MacVim perchance?

Comment: Also see https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/euxwou/netrw_strange_behavior_in_tree_view/

Comment: I am using vim (terminal/Linux)

Comment: I noticed the same problem with terminator in Ubuntu. Once I switched to another tab and then switched back, what used to be normal directories became files. And I need to close and open the parent directory in netrw to get it back to normal

Comment: I am definitely seeing this in MacVim almost 3 years later.